# Error using 'git add': "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: bash

I can not commit and pull because of an unmerged file.

```
U    user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG
fatal: 'commit' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I have tried `git add -A` and then commit, but it's still not working.
When I tried

```
git add user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG
```

it says

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Besides, I have manually removed the file and even the directory `post_img` and then committed again, but it remains the same. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
git add "user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG"
```

Otherwise, Bash will try to do something with that `(2)` in the file name.

If you removed the file and want to also remove it from Git, you have to call `rm` instead:

```
git rm "user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG"
```

Or you can also use `git add -u` to update files Git already knows about (which will remove the file too).

Comment: still not working because i have deleted the file and it says `can not match any`

Comment: If you have removed the file, you have to use `git rm "…"` instead.

Comment: Yes, I have already used git rm "...", and it says `user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG: needs merge
fatal: pathspec 'user_data/user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG' did not match any files`

Comment: It works, and I have to do something like `rm user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003\(2\).JPG 
`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
git add user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003\(2\).JPG.
```

It's the parentheses in the file name that are causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) lets you know what the syntax problem was all about:

```
   1  git add user_data/post_img/kesongxie/LuYWf7nM915SQ0X/003(2).JPG
                                                              ^––SC1070 Parsing stopped here because of parsing errors.
                                                              ^––SC1036 '(' is invalid here. Did you forget to escape it?
```

The way to resolve that is to escape the `(` and the `)`.  Just put a `\` before these and you will be fine - `\(` and `\)`

Comment: This is what happens if I escape parentheses:
`# git add ./**/*.\(po|mo\)
bash: mo): command not found`

Comment: That is an awesome tip. ShellCheck can apparently also be installed locally. E.g., [supposedly by](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#user-content-installing) `sudo apt install shellcheck` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Using ShellCheck, I was able to fix a Git hooks script in short order (rather than trying to search on Stack Overflow for the error messages - very, very inefficient. Sadly).